# How to return logical vector over set of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am searching for a series of values that could be present in any of 9 potential columns, and they all essentially represent the same thing, so I want to dichotomize those 9 columns into one for analysis.

```
    embolization = c("37200", "37211", "37213", "37214", "37236", "37237", "37238", "37239", "37241", "37242", "37243", "37244", "61624", "61626")
    embolization <- as.list(embolization)
    f = function(x) any(x == embolization, na.rm = FALSE)
apply(df2, MARGIN = 1, FUN = f)
```

when i run this function i get an error saying longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object. I would appreciate help or pointing me to the right direction.

here is a sample df.

```
     CPT1    CPT2    CPT3
1   49205   44015   38747
2   44015   38747   NULL
3   44015   38747   NULL
4   31624   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    NULL    NULL
6   43621   38747   44015
7   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Say i want any of the values (38747, 30984, and 34445) to end up as a new column to be true. so i want the final df output to look like this

```
     CPT1    CPT2    CPT3  newcol
1   49205   44015   38747  TRUE
2   44015   38747   NULL   TRUE
3   44015   38747   NULL   TRUE
4   31624   NULL    NULL   FALSE
5   NULL    NULL    NULL   FALSE
6   43621   38747   44015  TRUE
7   NULL    NULL    NULL   FALSE
```

Comment: Do you mean instead `function(x) any(x %in% embolization, na.rm = FALSE)`?

Comment: Why do you make `embolization` a list?

Comment: I am trying to search for any values within that list to return as TRUE if they are present in any of the columns, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you need to know which columns contain something from `embol`, or which elements in `embol` are found in one of the columns? Perhaps you could generate a small dummy dataset and expected output (manually generated) to show exactly what you need?

Comment: @r2evans, I attached an example. I want to know if the rows contain any of the listed values.

Comment: medlearning, RonakShah is being kind. When you give an example in your question, it really helps when it is consistent: if you say that one of "49205, 44015, 38747" is found within `embolization`, I full expect to see one of those three within the vector you defined in your question. Consider your question a small, compact unit-test, where all of the code should work as you want it to.

Comment: @r2evans i just chose those values because they are present within my df now to more clearly show my idea, it turns out the things I'm looking for are exceedingly rare and just wanted to be clear. sorry if that is a faux pas

Comment: I'm glad you got what you needed ... but it's frustrating trying to replicate your expected output when your input data will not produce it with correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `apply` you can use :

```
embolization <- c(38747, 30984, 34445)
df$newcol <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% embolization))
df

#   CPT1  CPT2  CPT3 newcol
#1 49205 44015 38747   TRUE
#2 44015 38747  NULL   TRUE
#3 44015 38747  NULL   TRUE
#4 31624  NULL  NULL  FALSE
#5  NULL  NULL  NULL  FALSE
#6 43621 38747 44015   TRUE
#7  NULL  NULL  NULL  FALSE
```

Or with `sapply` and `rowSums` :

```
df$newcol <- rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, embolization)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in a vectorized way in `base R` with `Reduce`

```
df$newcol <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `%in%`, embolization))
df$newcol
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(CPT1 = c("49205", "44015", "44015", "31624", "NULL", 
"43621", "NULL"), CPT2 = c("44015", "38747", "38747", "NULL", 
"NULL", "38747", "NULL"), CPT3 = c("38747", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
"NULL", "44015", "NULL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))

embolization <- c(38747, 30984, 34445)
```